# How to achieve "reddit post" type box with divs and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the Reddit post box but I have a couple of issues.

This is what I'm going for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kySBq.png

This is what I have so far:

```
.post_container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 75%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.top_info {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
 color: white;
}

<div class="post_container">
   <div class="left_side">
   </div>
   <div class="top_info">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have the example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/1gtjyxmk/2/

Mainly the problem is the left box that has the vote buttons and the score. I tried to make a child div and give it a height of 100%, but since the parent div height is determined by the content that doesn't work.

Now when I tried to place the vote buttons and score vertically in the middle of the container, they are in the middle of the page.

Also, something weird happens when I try to apply a border to the container like so:

```
.post_container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

.post-container {
  display: flex;
}


/*left side*/

.left-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70px;
  background: yellow;
}


/*main post*/
.post {
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.main-content p {
 padding: 10px;
}

.main-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.toptext {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div> U </div>
    <div> 55 </div>
    <div> D </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <p class="toptext">
      Published by webdev18 3h ago
    </p>
    <div class="main-content">
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc volutpat dignissim elit, quis placerat ex porttitor et.
      </p>
      <p class="contain">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed blandit aliquet turpis et fermentum. Integer mollis quis massa id auctor. Vestibulum ultricies facilisis turpis vel pellentesque.Phasellus nisl libero,
        laoreet eget sem et, aliquam tincidunt nisi. Aliquam vitae vulputate lectus, vel blandit felis. Aenean sit amet est tincidunt, interdum erat malesuada, aliquet est. Integer et felis velit. </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple table for that?

```js
$('.post_container .content div').animate({height: '300px'}, 3000);
```

```css
.post_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.post_container td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.post_container .left_side {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="post_container">
  <tr>
    <td class="left_side" rowspan="2">
      Left Side
    </td>
    <td class="top_info">
      Header
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="content">
      <div>Content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```